# Foursquare venues search and TOS

Tags: foursquare

I'm using another venues provider, but would like to search Foursquare from the venue results of that provider for Foursquare checkins.  Is this possible or would that be considered violating the TOS?

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the Policy at https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community ?

Whats written there as of writing this answer is that it is okay to extend their results with other data sources.

It is **not okay** to search across both foursquare and Google Places, then return a combination of their results/data.

What I would do if I am doing something I am not sure of is just ask them directly at https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/support

At the last paragraph they talk about policy (at the support page), says you can email them directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did read the TOS, that is why I'm asking about it.  The support links back to here to post questions.

Comment: Yes, but note at the last paragraph, they say that for Policy you can e-mail them directly